# Links under result in SERPS?

Tags: google-search

Sometimes when you google search, under a result will be links within that site eg 'contact', 'about', etc.  How does google decide weather to generate these and can you encourage it to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is automatic. There is no way to 'make' that happen.
It depends on how search friendly your site is,how long your site has been up on the web, hits, visits etc...

Comment: I think your right. Looking at the drupal site, the links in the SERPs are from all over the place.